# Drop address extension (+) part before forwarding with Postfix

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I need disposable email addresses with random address extensions such as:

```
api+test1@domain.net
api+test2@domain.net
...
```

All these addresses can be delivered to the local mailbox `api` without any problem, however, I have to forward them to a remote mail account `api@domain.com` (which does not recognize address extensions).

Here's the current config:

```
# main.cf
recipient_delimiter = +

# virtual
api@domain.net api@domain.com
```

The forward works, however, `api+test1@domain.net` is forwarded to `api+test1.domain.com` and can't be delivered there (since it does not recognize address extensions).

How can I "drop" the address extension before the mails are forwarded? In other words, how can I forward all addresses `api+*@domain.net` to `api@domain.com`?

(I've tried a canonical map `api+test1 api` which didn't do the trick.)

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: You can redirect extension addresses in `virtual` directly:

```
api+test1@domain.net api@domain.com
```

And with a `pcre` table instead of `hash`, one line can treat them all:

```
/^api+.+@domain.net$/ api@domain.com
```